# Running .NET on persistent RAM?

Tags: .net, nvme, persistent-memory

I have large indexes in memory for quick search in a huge dataset. It takes forever to build the indexes and it likewise take a long time to just deserialize a snapshot of them from disk to memory. And they use up a lot of precious/expensive RAM. I did make an attempt to use the indexes straight from disk with a kind of custom search-reader that just deserialized the required bits on-the-fly. This worked surprisingly well but did have some serious drawbacks in a multi-threaded environment regarding locks, concurrency, versioning etc. And it was not superfast of course.

Anyhow, I was wondering if "persistent RAM" (NVMe, Optane..?) could help me out here. I'm not sure I understand how they are supposed to be used exactly, but it seems they fill a gap between HDD/SSD and DDR-RAM? They cost less than RAM but are faster than SSD, and are persistent.

So what I was hoping for is to somehow run a .NET-program straight up on persistent RAM, with my indexes, and without having to serialize it back and forth to SSD between restarts. That would be a dream come true!

If not putting an entire .NET-program in persistent RAM, perhaps there are other ways of interfacing with it from .NET? Even if it's only writing and reading bytes?

Comment: in the "other options" bucket: "memory mapped files" may have some utility here, without having to go all the way to persistent RAM; but: what sort of payload size are we talking about here? 1GB? 10GB? 100GB? (size matters) - also, you say that deserializing it is too expensive right now; what kind of serialization technology are you using currently?

Comment: to be explicit: I don't think you could usefully use *managed objects* in any kind of persistent RAM - you'd be limited to things you can do with unmanaged memory; this means you can still use structs etc (as long as they don't contain references - so: no `string` data, for example), so understanding the data that you're trying to model is also pretty important here. Effectively, the features available to you in "memory mapped files" vs "persistent RAM" are broadly similar, but "memory mapped files" are more readily available for experimentation, without requiring special hardware/drivers.

Comment: Hi, the main problem is the cost of memory. The payload is large enough to be too expensive for me. Deserialization time is not a big problem and can be optimized. MMF could help with my custom reader I guess, but I still have a bigger problems with concurrency with that solution. ImmutableSortedDictionary is really the perfect fit for my use case. Is there any technical reason why not managed memory on persistent RAM is possible? I mean if it's technically possible it would be a revolutionary feature for .NET?

Comment: you're asking for a managed heap outside of process memory; that's *incredibly* complex, and is not remotely supported currently; you'd also need a new heap-specific allocation API (to allocate objects on the special heap rather than the regular heap). As for the fundamental task you're trying to achieve: again, can I ask what size we're talking about here, and what the data looks like? this is an area I know a lot about, and have done a lot of interesting things in, but it is very hard to give useful guidance without a lot more context.

Comment: to emphasize: a memory mapped file is a: very performant, and b: doesn't allocate *anything* (it just maps in pages using OS-level IO primitives; combine that with an SSD and you're mostly set)

Comment: I'm targeting about 1 TB of memory usage for the indexes and they contain standard .NET primitives (and strings) in dictionaries. I guess I'll stick to my current plan to only have the most important indexes in memory and put the rest on disk and access it through MMF and my custom reader. But thanks for the insights Marc! Much appreciated.

Comment: So I should be thinking of persistent RAM more like faster SSD than cheaper RAM (as in usable by the OS for running programs in)?

Comment: ok, 1TB is far above what you want in "managed" memory - that is going to make the GC weep, frankly; this is a complex scenario, but would indeed be one where my first approach would be MMF. However, this is far beyond the scale where it is possible to give casual answers.